# gradle sync issues: CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QibFC.png)I'm a beginner trying to learn android studio. I didn't have any problems until this morning and I've already created multiple practice projects and they all worked fine. However, on one of the projects when I tried to run the emulator it kept giving me this error message that I've never encountered before: CreateProcess error=2, the system cannot find the file specified. After a moment of searching for help, I thought it was an update issue so I updated everything to the latest version. But things haven't changed and I only get an additional error message saying: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly. 
What have I done? I don't recall removing any file and relocating anything. I don't understand how could such thing just happen. 
I've checked my [Project Structure] and it says that I'm using 
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.5.0
Gradle Version: 5.4.1
Please help...

Here is my Gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.techtown.samplelayoutinflater1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can you please add your gradle file code in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but where is this gradle file code? Is it the error message? I'm really a beginner...

Comment: in the left panel you will find gradle Script package in the bottom, there you will find build.gradle (Module: app)  file.

Comment: @FurqanKhan I've edited my post. Could you take a look? Thank you so much

Comment: You have added a project level build.gradle. there will be one more with Module :app please post that here

Comment: @FurqanKhan Is that the one you are talking about?

Comment: yes thank you, now can you post a whole log that you get when you try to run the code.

Comment: @FurqanKhan I have added the image in my post. I haven't tried to run the emulator though..after I tried to solve this by doing an update whenever I click run I get edit configuration pop up with a warning that says "Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again".    The image I uploaded is what I got after I created a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle script was tuned for Linux, not for Windows. On Windows, you need "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd" instead of "$ndkDir/ndk-build".

But even better, if you use the Android Studio 3.2 or later, rewrite your gradle script to use the new NDK integration, see the official walkthrough.

Here is how build.gradle may look:

```
         apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

               android {
                compileSdkVersion 23
                 buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prouast.heartbeat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    implementation project(':libraries:opencv')
}

android {
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot guarantee that your src/main/jni/Android.mk will work correctly on your Windows machine. Also, make sure that you use compatible versions of NDK and Gradle plugin